# Java, closing a frame from another frame/class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame

I am making a java program, and I need to close a frame.
When I click on the search icon, an `ActionListener` will react and will make the same frame with 4 extra buttons.
So now I have got 2 frames (1 with 4 extra buttons on the top and 1 that doesn't).
How can iI close the frame that has no button, so that "frame" closes and "frame1" will stay open?
My code:
http://pastebin.com/ZKnfRt2Y

I tried frame.dispose(); but that didn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with posting your code here?

Comment: I always post them on pastebin.

Comment: Make a habit of posting them here. Question are for the benefit of all, not just the original poster. Any future readers will want to see the code you're having problems with.

Comment: You wish to consider taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice.  You should consider simply updating the current frame to reflect the new state...

Comment: What do you mean "it didnt work"? Did it not let you? From what I read, it should've said it has no idea what "frame" is.

Comment: Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern GUI interface design. You do not control the rendering pipeline of different platforms and each will change the amount of pixels it needs to render certain ui elements, like fonts. This will take you "perfect" layout on your machine and turn into gibberish on someone elses. Make use of approriate layout managers

Comment: @captianroxors it says that it cannot be referenced from a satic context

Comment: Aha. Key piece of information there. Gotta let folks know when errors occurred. Helps track down problems super fast.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the other class the pointer to the original frame so you can actually make use of its dispose method.
Also, all the static classes are a bit much. I recommend anonymous inner types where needed.

This'll do exactly what you asked for

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

// hoofdclasse
public class Adresboek extends JFrame {

    // opstartclasse
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // maak een frame
        JFrame frame = new Adresboek();
        frame.setSize(335, 395);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Adresboek");
        frame.setContentPane(new Gast1(frame));
        // frame.setContentPane(new Beheer1());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    // het paneel
    static class Gast1 extends JPanel {

        // de knoppen, textvelden en labels
        private JTextField TF1_VNaam, TF1_TussenVoegsel, TF1_ANaam, TF1_Straat, TF1_SNummer, TF1_Postcode,
                TF1_Plaatsnaam, TF1_GD, TF1_Tel, TF1_Email, TF1_Zoeken;
        private JLabel L1_VNaam, L1_TussenVoegsel, L1_ANaam, L1_Straat, L1_Postcode, L1_Plaatsnaam, L1_GD, L1_Tel,
                L1_Email;
        private JButton B1_Instellingen, B1_Zoeken, B1_Vorige, B1_Volgende;

        public Gast1(final JFrame maker) {
            super();

            // layout manager uit
            setLayout(null);

            // Textvelden
            TF1_VNaam = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_TussenVoegsel = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_ANaam = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Straat = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_SNummer = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Postcode = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Plaatsnaam = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_GD = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Tel = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Email = new JTextField(10);
            TF1_Zoeken = new JTextField(10);

            // Labels
            L1_VNaam = new JLabel("Voornaam:");
            L1_TussenVoegsel = new JLabel("Tussenvoegsel:");
            L1_ANaam = new JLabel("Achternaam:");
            L1_Straat = new JLabel("Straat + Nr:");
            L1_Postcode = new JLabel("Postcode:");
            L1_Plaatsnaam = new JLabel("Plaatsnaam:");
            L1_GD = new JLabel("Geboortedatum:");
            L1_Tel = new JLabel("Telefoon:");
            L1_Email = new JLabel("E-mail:");

            // Knoppen
            ImageIcon login2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("instellingen.png"));
            B1_Instellingen = new JButton(login2);
            ImageIcon search = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("search.png"));
            B1_Zoeken = new JButton(search);
            B1_Vorige = new JButton("<<");
            B1_Volgende = new JButton(">>");

            // plaatsing
            // textvelden
            TF1_VNaam.setBounds(110, 50, 210, 25);
            TF1_TussenVoegsel.setBounds(110, 80, 210, 25);
            TF1_ANaam.setBounds(110, 110, 210, 25);
            TF1_Straat.setBounds(110, 140, 160, 25);
            TF1_SNummer.setBounds(275, 140, 45, 25);
            TF1_Postcode.setBounds(110, 170, 210, 25);
            TF1_Plaatsnaam.setBounds(110, 200, 210, 25);
            TF1_GD.setBounds(110, 230, 210, 25);
            TF1_Tel.setBounds(110, 260, 210, 25);
            TF1_Email.setBounds(110, 290, 210, 25);
            TF1_Zoeken.setBounds(10, 330, 140, 26);

            // labels
            L1_VNaam.setBounds(10, 50, 90, 25);
            L1_TussenVoegsel.setBounds(10, 80, 90, 25);
            L1_ANaam.setBounds(10, 110, 90, 25);
            L1_Straat.setBounds(10, 140, 90, 25);
            L1_Postcode.setBounds(10, 170, 90, 25);
            L1_Plaatsnaam.setBounds(10, 200, 90, 25);
            L1_GD.setBounds(10, 230, 95, 25);
            L1_Tel.setBounds(10, 260, 90, 25);
            L1_Email.setBounds(10, 290, 90, 25);

            // knoppen
            B1_Instellingen.setBounds(265, 10, 50, 25);
            B1_Zoeken.setBounds(155, 330, 50, 25);
            B1_Vorige.setBounds(210, 330, 50, 25);
            B1_Volgende.setBounds(265, 330, 50, 25);

            // Font
            Font Font1 = new Font(B1_Instellingen.getFont().getName(), B1_Instellingen.getFont().getStyle(), 11);
            Font Font2 = new Font(B1_Zoeken.getFont().getName(), B1_Zoeken.getFont().getStyle(), 11);
            Font Font3 = new Font(B1_Vorige.getFont().getName(), B1_Vorige.getFont().getStyle(), 11);
            Font Font4 = new Font(B1_Volgende.getFont().getName(), B1_Volgende.getFont().getStyle(), 11);

            // instellen Font
            B1_Instellingen.setFont(Font1);
            B1_Zoeken.setFont(Font2);
            B1_Vorige.setFont(Font3);
            B1_Volgende.setFont(Font4);

            // het toevoegen van de velden, labels en knoppen
            // toevoegen velden
            add(TF1_VNaam);
            add(TF1_TussenVoegsel);
            add(TF1_ANaam);
            add(TF1_Straat);
            add(TF1_SNummer);
            add(TF1_Postcode);
            add(TF1_Plaatsnaam);
            add(TF1_GD);
            add(TF1_Tel);
            add(TF1_Email);
            add(TF1_Zoeken);

            // toevoegen labels
            add(L1_VNaam);
            add(L1_TussenVoegsel);
            add(L1_ANaam);
            add(L1_Straat);
            add(L1_Postcode);
            add(L1_Plaatsnaam);
            add(L1_GD);
            add(L1_Tel);
            add(L1_Email);

            // toevoegen knoppen
            add(B1_Instellingen);
            add(B1_Zoeken);
            add(B1_Vorige);
            add(B1_Volgende);

//Anonymous inner classes FTW
            B1_Zoeken.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Hello Bestand!");
                    JFrame frame1 = new Adresboek();
                    frame1.setSize(335, 395);
                    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame1.setTitle("Adresboek1");
                    frame1.setContentPane(new Beheer1(frame1));
                    frame1.setVisible(true);
                    frame1.setResizable(false);
                    maker.dispose();
                }
            });


        }// sluit de constructor af

    }

    // Class Beheer
    static class Beheer1 extends Gast1 {

        // de knoppen, textvelden en labels
        private JButton B1_Wijzigen, B1_Aanmaken, B1_Verwijderen, B1_Opslaan, B1_Instellingen;

        public Beheer1(JFrame maker) {
            super(maker);

            // Images Knoppen
            ImageIcon edit = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("aanpas.png"));
            ImageIcon add = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("nieuw.png"));
            ImageIcon delete = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("verwijderen.png"));
            ImageIcon save = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("opslaan.png"));
            ImageIcon login = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("instellingen.png"));


            // Knoppen Aanmaken
            B1_Wijzigen = new JButton(edit);
            B1_Aanmaken = new JButton(add);
            B1_Verwijderen = new JButton(delete);
            B1_Opslaan = new JButton(save);
            B1_Instellingen = new JButton(login);

            // Plaatsing
            this.B1_Wijzigen.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 25);
            this.B1_Aanmaken.setBounds(62, 10, 50, 25);
            this.B1_Verwijderen.setBounds(114, 10, 50, 25);
            this.B1_Opslaan.setBounds(166, 10, 50, 25);
            this.B1_Instellingen.setBounds(265, 10, 50, 25);

            // Knoppen Toevoegen
            add(B1_Wijzigen);
            add(B1_Aanmaken);
            add(B1_Verwijderen);
            add(B1_Opslaan);
            add(B1_Instellingen);
        }
    }
}
```

but i'd strongly recommend taking MadProgrammer's advice and just manipulate your current frame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple windows, you should make use a `CardLayout` and simply switch between the views...

Normally, I'd have a nice central controller/model making this work, but I've simply hacked you code to demonstrate the idea...

When you create the main frame, set it's layout manager to `CardLayout` and add both panels...

```
public class Adresboek extends JFrame {

    //opstartclasse
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                //maak een frame
                JFrame frame = new Adresboek();
                frame.setSize(335, 395);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setTitle("Adresboek");

                frame.setLayout(new CardLayout());

                // These are the available views...
                frame.add(new Gast1(), "Gast");
                frame.add(new Beheer1(), "Beheer");

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

When the `instellingenhandler` `actionPerformed` method is triggered, simply switch views...

```
class instellingenhandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("...");
        JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(Gast1.this);
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) rootPane.getContentPane().getLayout();
        layout.show(rootPane.getContentPane(), "Beheer");
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.

Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern GUI interface design. You do not control the rendering pipeline of different platforms and each will change the amount of pixels it needs to render certain ui elements, like fonts. This will take you "perfect" layout on your machine and turn into gibberish on someone elses. Make use of appropriate layout managers

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

You may also find [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) worth a read